# How do you round a floating point number in Perl?

Tags: perl, floating-point, rounding

How can I round a decimal number (floating point) to the nearest integer?

e.g.

```
1.2 = 1
1.7 = 2
```

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Output of [`perldoc -q round`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Does-Perl-have-a-round%28)-function%3f--What-about-ceil()-and-floor()%3f--Trig-functions%3f)

> Does Perl have a round() function?  What about ceil() and floor()?
> Trig functions?
>
> Remember that [`int()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html) merely truncates toward `0`.  For rounding to a certain number of digits, [`sprintf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) or [`printf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) is usually the easiest
> route.
>
> ```
>     printf("%.3f", 3.1415926535);       # prints 3.142
> ```
>
> The [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module (part of the standard Perl distribution) implements
> `ceil()`, `floor()`, and a number of other mathematical and trigonometric
> functions.
>
> ```
>     use POSIX;
>     $ceil   = ceil(3.5);                        # 4
>     $floor  = floor(3.5);                       # 3
> ```
>
> In 5.000 to 5.003 perls, trigonometry was done in the [`Math::Complex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/Complex.html)
> module.  With 5.004, the [`Math::Trig`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/Trig.html) module (part of the standard Perl
> distribution) implements the trigonometric functions. Internally it
> uses the [`Math::Complex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Math/Complex.html) module and some functions can break out from the
> real axis into the complex plane, for example the inverse sine of 2.
>
> Rounding in financial applications can have serious implications, and
> the rounding method used should be specified precisely.  In these
> cases, it probably pays not to trust whichever system rounding is being
> used by Perl, but to instead implement the rounding function you need
> yourself.
>
> To see why, notice how you'll still have an issue on half-way-point
> alternation:
>
> ```
>     for ($i = 0; $i < 1.01; $i += 0.05) { printf "%.1f ",$i}
>
>     0.0 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7
>     0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 1.0 1.0
> ```
>
> Don't blame Perl.  It's the same as in C.  IEEE says we have to do
> this.  Perl numbers whose absolute values are integers under `2**31` (on
> 32 bit machines) will work pretty much like mathematical integers.
> Other numbers are not guaranteed.

Comment: ^ Thariama, why would ceil be deprecated? It's not deprecated in POSIX or perl as far as I know. Citation needed!

Comment: @Beginners, don't try to use `printf` if you want the result in a variable, use `sprintf`... hope this saves you some debugging-time :-P

Comment: Can I use `int()` on PDLs?

Comment: use POSIX; <br/>
$x = ($x - floor($x) >= .5) ? ceil($x) : floor($x);

Answer (score 154):

Whilst not disagreeing with the complex answers about half-way marks and so on, for the more common (and possibly trivial) use-case:

`my $rounded = int($float + 0.5);`

**UPDATE**

If it's possible for your `$float` to be negative, the following variation will produce the correct result:

`my $rounded = int($float + $float/abs($float*2 || 1));`

With this calculation -1.4 is rounded to -1, and -1.6 to -2, and zero won't explode.

Comment: ... but it fails on negative numbers: still better sprintf

Comment: Ah no, it does not. Rounding up a negative number takes you closer to zero, not further away. What are they teaching in schools these days?

Comment: @RET Yes, it does fail with negative numbers. $float=-1.4 results in 0 with this method. That is not what they taught at my school. Remember that int() truncates towards zero.

Comment: @fishinear You are correct, and I am duly chastened. But I did say 'for trivial use-case'. My answer has been corrected.

Comment: For instances where I was just correcting for floating points incapable of reaching an integer, I used this modified solution: my $rounded = floor($float + 0.1);

Comment: Note that it $float = 0, this will fail :-)

Comment: @mat That's a correction that's been a long time coming! Duly fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ancient post, but I don't see why the code should become complicated for negatives: `$rounded = int(abs($float) + 0.5); $rounded = $float * -1 if $float < 0;` is much simpler and 25% faster when I bench it with positive values (loses a bit of the advantage with negatives). You can even write it in a single line with the ternary operator if you HAVE to: `int(abs($float) + 0.5)*($float < 0 ? -1 : 1);` still easier to understand and faster...

Answer (score 81):

You can either use a module like [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Round):

```
use Math::Round;
my $rounded = round( $float );
```

Or you can do it the crude way:

```
my $rounded = sprintf "%.0f", $float;
```

Answer (score 49):

If you decide to use printf or sprintf, note that they use the [Round half to even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) method.

```
foreach my $i ( 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5 ) {
    printf "$i -> %.0f\n", $i;
}
__END__
0.5 -> 0
1.5 -> 2
2.5 -> 2
3.5 -> 4
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

More precisely, the name of the method is 'Round Half to Even'.

Comment: All the answers that mention printf, or sprintf should mention this.

Comment: This is an extremly important information. I had serveral times bugs in software because I assumed 5 will always be rounded up. I finally found, why perl never did what I wanted. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Actually, this is OS dependent! In Windows it will round half away from zero and unix-like will round half to even: http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: @Apoc It is defined as "round to nearest (integer) ties to even" in [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest). Nearest is any integer that is less than 0.5 (in magnitude) away. If it happens that the number is **exactly** half way (a tie) then round to even. Yes, Windows does not follow the IEEE spec.

Answer (score 9):

See [perldoc/perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html):

> Remember that `int()` merely truncates toward 0.  For rounding to a
>   certain number of digits, `sprintf()` or `printf()` is usually the
>   easiest route.
>
> ```
>  printf("%.3f",3.1415926535);
>  # prints 3.142
> ```
>
> The `POSIX` module (part of the standard Perl distribution)
>   implements `ceil()`, `floor()`, and a number of other mathematical
>   and trigonometric functions.
>
> ```
> use POSIX;
> $ceil  = ceil(3.5); # 4
> $floor = floor(3.5); # 3
> ```
>
> In 5.000 to 5.003 perls, trigonometry was done in the `Math::Complex` module.
>
> With 5.004, the `Math::Trig` module (part of the standard Perl distribution) > implements the trigonometric functions.
>
> Internally it uses the `Math::Complex` module and some functions can break
>   out from the real axis into the complex plane, for example the inverse sine of 2.
>
> Rounding in financial applications can have serious implications, and the rounding
>   method used should be specified precisely.  In these cases, it probably pays not to
>   trust whichever system rounding is being used by Perl, but to instead implement the
>   rounding function you need yourself.
>
> To see why, notice how you'll still have an issue on half-way-point alternation:
>
> ```
> for ($i = 0; $i < 1.01; $i += 0.05)
> {
>    printf "%.1f ",$i
> }
>
> 0.0 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.4 0.5 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.7 0.8 0.8 0.9 0.9 1.0 1.0
> ```
>
> Don't blame Perl.  It's the same as in C.  IEEE says we have to do
>   this. Perl numbers whose absolute values are integers under 2**31 (on
>   32 bit machines) will work pretty much like mathematical integers.
>   Other numbers are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any external module.

```
$x[0] = 1.2;
$x[1] = 1.7;

foreach (@x){
  print $_.' = '.( ( ($_-int($_))<0.5) ? int($_) : int($_)+1 );
  print "\n";
}
```

I may be missing your point, but I thought this was much cleaner way to do the same job.

What this does is to walk through every positive number in the element, print the number and rounded integer in the format you mentioned. The code concatenates respective rounded positive integer only based on the decimals. int($_) basically *round-down* the number so ($*-int($*)) captures the decimals. If the decimals are (by definition) strictly less than 0.5, round-down the number. If not, round-up by adding 1.

Comment: Once again, why answer an ancient question with a complicated answer when something like RET's answer works equally well.

Comment: This really isn't very complicated, and RET's answer involves a bunch of math that a) theoretically risks overflow, b) takes longer, and c) needlessly introduces more fp imprecision to your final value.  Wait, which one is complicated again? ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following will round positive or negative numbers to a given decimal position:

```
sub round ()
{
    my ($x, $pow10) = @_;
    my $a = 10 ** $pow10;

    return (int($x / $a + (($x < 0) ? -0.5 : 0.5)) * $a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a sample of five different ways to summate values. The first is a naive way to perform the summation (and fails). The second attempts to use `sprintf()`, but it too fails. The third uses `sprintf()` successfully while the final two (4th & 5th) use `floor($value + 0.5)`.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use POSIX;

 my @values = (26.67,62.51,62.51,62.51,68.82,79.39,79.39);
 my $total1 = 0.00;
 my $total2 = 0;
 my $total3 = 0;
 my $total4 = 0.00;
 my $total5 = 0;
 my $value1;
 my $value2;
 my $value3;
 my $value4;
 my $value5;

 foreach $value1 (@values)
 {
      $value2 = $value1;
      $value3 = $value1;
      $value4 = $value1;
      $value5 = $value1;

      $total1 += $value1;

      $total2 += sprintf('%d', $value2 * 100);

      $value3 = sprintf('%1.2f', $value3);
      $value3 =~ s/\.//;
      $total3 += $value3;

      $total4 += $value4;

      $total5 += floor(($value5 * 100.0) + 0.5);
 }

 $total1 *= 100;
 $total4 = floor(($total4 * 100.0) + 0.5);

 print '$total1: '.sprintf('%011d', $total1)."\n";
 print '$total2: '.sprintf('%011d', $total2)."\n";
 print '$total3: '.sprintf('%011d', $total3)."\n";
 print '$total4: '.sprintf('%011d', $total4)."\n";
 print '$total5: '.sprintf('%011d', $total5)."\n";

 exit(0);

 #$total1: 00000044179
 #$total2: 00000044179
 #$total3: 00000044180
 #$total4: 00000044180
 #$total5: 00000044180
```

Note that `floor($value + 0.5)` can be replaced with `int($value + 0.5)` to remove the dependency on `POSIX`.

Answer (score 1):

Negative numbers can add some quirks that people need to be aware of.

`printf`-style approaches give us correct numbers, but they can result in some odd displays. We have discovered that this method (in my opinion, stupidly) puts in a `-` sign whether or not it should or shouldn't. For example, -0.01 rounded to one decimal place returns a -0.0, rather than just 0. If you are going to do the `printf` style approach, and you know you want no decimal, use `%d` and not `%f` (when you need decimals, it's when the display gets wonky).

While it's correct and for math no big deal, for display it just looks weird showing something like "-0.0".

For the int method, negative numbers can change what you want as a result (though there are some arguments that can be made they are correct).

The `int + 0.5` causes real issues with -negative numbers, unless you want it to work that way, but I imagine most people don't. -0.9 should probably round to -1, not 0. If you know that you want negative to be a ceiling rather than a floor then you can do it in one-liner, otherwise, you might want to use the int method with a minor modification (this obviously only works to get back whole numbers:

```
my $var = -9.1;
my $tmpRounded = int( abs($var) + 0.5));
my $finalRounded = $var >= 0 ? 0 + $tmpRounded : 0 - $tmpRounded;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with getting an integer value out of a whole floating point number (i.e. 12347.9999 or 54321.0001), this approach (borrowed and modified from above) will do the trick:

```
my $rounded = floor($float + 0.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for sprintf

```
if ($value =~ m/\d\..*5$/){
    $format =~ /.*(\d)f$/;
    if (defined $1){
       my $coef = "0." . "0" x $1 . "05";    
            $value = $value + $coef;    
    }
}

$value = sprintf( "$format", $value );
```

Answer (score 0):

loads of reading documentation on how to round numbers, many experts suggest writing your own rounding routines, as the 'canned' version provided with your language may not be precise enough, or contain errors.  i imagine, however, they're talking many decimal places not just one, two, or three.  with that in mind, here is my solution (although not EXACTLY as requested as my needs are to display dollars - the process is not much different, though).

```
sub asDollars($) {
  my ($cost) = @_;
  my $rv = 0;

  my $negative = 0;
  if ($cost =~ /^-/) {
    $negative = 1;
    $cost =~ s/^-//;
  }

  my @cost = split(/\./, $cost);

  # let's get the first 3 digits of $cost[1]
  my ($digit1, $digit2, $digit3) = split("", $cost[1]);
  # now, is $digit3 >= 5?
  # if yes, plus one to $digit2.
  # is $digit2 > 9 now?
  # if yes, $digit2 = 0, $digit1++
  # is $digit1 > 9 now??
  # if yes, $digit1 = 0, $cost[0]++
  if ($digit3 >= 5) {
    $digit3 = 0;
    $digit2++;
    if ($digit2 > 9) {
      $digit2 = 0;
      $digit1++;
      if ($digit1 > 9) {
        $digit1 = 0;
        $cost[0]++;
      }
    }
  }
  $cost[1] = $digit1 . $digit2;
  if ($digit1 ne "0" and $cost[1] < 10) { $cost[1] .= "0"; }

  # and pretty up the left of decimal
  if ($cost[0] > 999) { $cost[0] = commafied($cost[0]); }

  $rv = join(".", @cost);

  if ($negative) { $rv = "-" . $rv; }

  return $rv;
}

sub commafied($) {
  #*
  # to insert commas before every 3rd number (from the right)
  # positive or negative numbers
  #*
  my ($num) = @_; # the number to insert commas into!

  my $negative = 0;
  if ($num =~ /^-/) {
    $negative = 1;
    $num =~ s/^-//;
  }
  $num =~ s/^(0)*//; # strip LEADING zeros from given number!
  $num =~ s/0/-/g; # convert zeros to dashes because ... computers!

  if ($num) {
    my @digits = reverse split("", $num);
    $num = "";

    for (my $i = 0; $i < @digits; $i += 3) {
      $num .= $digits[$i];
      if ($digits[$i+1]) { $num .= $digits[$i+1]; }
      if ($digits[$i+2]) { $num .= $digits[$i+2]; }
      if ($i < (@digits - 3)) { $num .= ","; }
      if ($i >= @digits) { last; }
    }

    #$num =~ s/,$//;
    $num = join("", reverse split("", $num));
    $num =~ s/-/0/g;
  }

  if ($negative) { $num = "-" . $num; }

  return $num; # a number with commas added
  #usage: my $prettyNum = commafied(1234567890);
}
```

Comment: to make the subroutine conform to your specifications, simply modify the following:

`if ($digit3 >= 5) {
    $digit3 = 0;
    $digit2++;
    if ($digit2 > 9) {
      $digit2 = 0;
      $digit1++;
      if ($digit1 > 9) {
        $digit1 = 0;
        $cost[0]++;
      }
    }
  }`

so it's:

`if ($digit1 >= 5) {
   $digit1 = 0;
   $cost[0]++;
 }`

then just `return commafied($cost[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Math::BigFloat`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Math::BigFloat) you can do something like this:

```
use Math::BigFloat;

print Math::BigFloat->new(1.2)->bfround(1); ## 1
print Math::BigFloat->new(1.7)->bfround(1); ## 2
```

This can be wrapped in a subroutine

```
use Math::BigFloat;

sub round {
  Math::BigFloat->new(shift)->bfround(1);
}

print round(1.2); ## 1
print round(1.7); ## 2
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cat table |
  perl -ne '/\d+\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/ && print "".**int**(log($1)/log(2))."\t$2\n";'
```