# Perl sprintf integer issue

Tags: perl

With this line, I expect the output `201`

```
$ perl -e '$e = '2.01'; $c = sprintf("%d", $e * 100); print $c;'
```

But I get `200` instead. I don't understand why.

Comment: @rojo Yeah, it works with `%f` but it should also work with `%d`.

Comment: No. No, it shouldn't.

Comment: 1/100 is a periodic number in binary, just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal. It is impossible to store it accurately in a floating point number.

Comment: @ikegami so how can we use `int` instead of `float` with Perl?

Comment: An integer can't store 1/100 either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the binary representation of a float number.

Try:

```
perl -e '$e = 2.01;printf("%2.25f\n",$e);'
```

**Output:**

```
2.0099999999999997868371793
```

The intetger part of this number multiplied by 100 gives 200

Comment: That command doesn't produce that output, even if you fix the unbalanced quotes.

Comment: @Borodin: I've copied/pasted the wrong part of my test. Now it' OK.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'my $e = "2.01"; my $c = sprintf("%.0f", $e * 100); print $c;'
```

With `%d`, the integer is truncated.

And if you don't bother with `printf` :

```
perl -e 'my $e = "2.01"; my $c = $e * 100; print $c;'
```

Comment: I agree with your but it should also work with `%d`, right? 201 is still an integer...

Comment: @coin But `2.01` is not. And internally it might not be saved as exactly that value but a tiny bit more or less. And then truncating it may get you a wrong result. As a rule of thumb, never interpret floats as integers without actually rounding.

Comment: @DeVadder So what's the proper way to get `201` from `'2.01'` ?

Comment: @coin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178539/how-do-you-round-a-floating-point-number-in-perl has you covered. The easiest way to round a *POSITIVE* float into an integer is probably `my $int = int($float + 0.5);` Obviously that may become a problem if behavior for values near to .5 are important for you and *DOES NOT WORK* for negative values (because `int` always truncates to zero). As such using it is certainly a bad habit.

Comment: @sputnick: `%d` *doesn't round the integer: that is the whole problem. If it did, the output would be `201`. It *truncates* it towards zero.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point representation has a limit to its accuracy, and the binary representation of `2.01` just happens to be fractionally *less* than 2.01.

The `%d` format conversion *truncates* the value to the next lowest value. It actually does a call to [`int`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html), whose documentation says

> You should not use this function for rounding: one because it truncates towards 0 , and two because machine representations of floating-point numbers can sometimes produce counterintuitive results.

And `int(200.99999999999)` is 200, which is what you are getting.

The canonical way in Perl to get the closest integer to a floating point value is to use the `%f` conversion with zero decimal points. So if you write instead

```
perl -e '$e = '2.01'; $c = sprintf("%.0f", $e * 100); print $c;'
```

you will get the output

```
200
```

Answer (score 0):

Following document mentions about floating point and binary representation. This is from python.org, but it also works for perl.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

```
$ perl -e 'if (2.01 + 2.01 + 2.01 == 6.03) { print "yes" } else { print "no" }'
no
```

You can try using `bignum` pragma as a makeshift:

```
$ perl -Mbignum -e '$e = "2.01"; $c = sprintf("%d", $e * 100); print $c;'
201
```