# Perl get file age, round numbers

Tags: perl, solaris

I have the following command.

```
perl -l -e 'print -M $ARGV[0], " days"' $testfile
```

It works fine, in that it gives me the correct age, and works on solaris, linux, unix, as required.

However, the format is

```
"1.000000394945 days."
```

I'd like to round this down to make the post-processing easier to something like

```
"1.00 days."
```

Any idea how one might modify this to make them whole numbers?

Comment: And if you want integers, see [How do you round a floating point number in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/178539/176646)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html):

```
perl -l -e 'printf "%.2f days", -M $ARGV[0]' file
```